# Read-Only mode for the OS - best way to make an inaccessible SD card last longer?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card, readonly

It's for a book navigation device for street children, using recycled laptop LCD's where the SD card would be encapsulated in cement and very difficult to change.

If the bits of an SD card are not re-written to every number of years, they will fade and fail? so a current should go through them in write mode every so often.

Can write mode can also help to re-allocate bad sectors and vary the locations of intensely read sectors?

Comment: The data sheet of a good SD card should contain information about the minimum possible read cycles. And if you can't change it, you should not use on-name stuff. As far as I know, the wear leveling is implemented in the SD card, so the problem is not Linux-related and probably better addressed in a different SE site. Finally: I would strongly recommend to offer an alternative boot source to revive a device that won't boot anymore; a Raspi with an SD card will never be a robust system.

Comment: Thanks, I found this about wear levelling via SD onboard ARM processors. apparently they dont all have wear levelling? https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/ex7dvo/quick_reminder_that_sd_cards_with_wearleveling/  I'll probably find a guide for options like disabling atime acces time updates and other wear accelerating processes.